# No ping from websocket in AspNetCore

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-core, websocket

I'm attempting an implementation of asp.net core's websocket, and am finding that I can't make the server ping the client to confirm alive at any interval whatsoever. The browser never registers any ping frames.

For testing purposes I am basically replicating Microsoft's code so my code is like in this demo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.0 
which basically means that the config for the websocket is:

```
        var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
        {
            KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            ReceiveBufferSize = 4 * 1024
        };
        app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
```

I have attempted deploying both on IIS express and on local IIS. Everything else works fine so far, all data frames register well. For monitoring I am using chrome's dev tools.

Versions used - AspNetCore.All (2.0.7) -> WebSockets (2.0.2)

Am I doing something wrong here or is the api broken ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few learnings here:

1. Chrome DevTools will not show websocket ping frames
2. The KeepAliveInterval as of this writing is broken

To manipulate the ping interval one must do it in IIS settings like so:

```
<system.webServer>
   <webSocket
      enabled="true" 
      receiveBufferLimit="4194304"
      pingInterval="00:01:00">
   </webSocket>
</system.webServer>
```

References:

1. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2464#issuecomment-390683383
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket